# Are the sentences with the word "aplomb" correct?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage

I am unsure of all the ways aplomb can be used in a sentence. For example:

> Ken was hitting Jordan, but Jordan did not fight back in anger but rather handled the situation with immaculate aplomb.

I have seen many sentence examples in which there is always the word "with" before "aplomb" (with aplomb, with considerable aplomb, with astonishing aplomb, etc). But can I use the word "aplomb" without the word "with"? For example:

> Although the other guy was attacking him, he did not fight back and instead reamained aplomb.

Is the sentence I stated above correct? Can I use the word "aplomb" without having the word "with" or will "aplomb" always have the word "with" before it either directly (i.e with aplomb) or with an adjective to emphasize on its meaning (i.e with astonishing aplomb).

Comment: Hello, Saim. Dictionaries provide example sentences showing correct usages. Has your research not provided any answers?

Comment: I did look on multiple websites to see and they all used aplomb with the word "with" before it. But word hippo's classic literature section showed a few sentences that made me question the ways it can be used. For example: She had a quiet aplomb, which would be called 'sang-froid' in a man.

Comment: Aplomb is a noun, like the word 'style'. You can't remain style. She could have a quiet and peaceful style, though I don't know how anyone can be composed and noisy.

Comment: [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/aplomb) shows some idiomatic premodifiers. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/aplomb) has a range of example sentences; the string 'typically jingoistic aplomb' stands out. // Even Wiktionary offers no support for an adjectival usage.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the help. Also, what are idiomatic premodifiers?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Are you suggesting that *she could have a quiet a peaceful aplomb* is fine? If not, it's not a good analogy.

Comment: Saying *she could have a quiet and peaceful aplomb* is not wrong, but it is repetitive. The word aplomb covers all that. If you have aplomb, you carry yourself with grace, elegance, even humility. Proud of yourself but not bragging or loud. So of course you are quiet and peaceful.

Comment: @YosefBaskin In French, *agir avec aplomb* does not imply grace or humility. On the contrary, it is often provocative.